# Get the values that are not Date values with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Two of the columns in my table are insertDate and ModifiedDate bothare NOT date datatype but varchar.
when I queried the table I got strange chars inserted into that date columns, something like // at this moment. Next time it may be something else.
I don't want to get into how did this value got in there..it's quite complicated.

All I need now is to query these values from these two columns out using Oracle 11g? something like:

```
 Select insertDate,ModifiedDate 
 from mytable
 where IsDate(insertDate ) <> 'NO' OR IsDate(ModifiedDate) <> 'NO'
```

Is there function like that inOracle 11g that can help me get those non date values?

Comment: How can you have strange characters in date columns? You probably have varchar columns. Given this, you have to know which format(s) you consider valid or not for a date to apply a check on the values

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant they are not date datatype, yes varchar2

Comment: Ok, but you have to understand which format you want to consider correct. Es. 01/01/2018, 01-jAn-18, 01,January 2018, ...

Comment: any that can be converted to a date I think.

Comment: In theory even "the first of January 2018" can be... :) you need some rules

Comment: The acceptable value is in this format 11/30/2017

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function based on [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) and then use it to check your values:

```
create or replace function checkDate(v in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    d date;
begin
    d :=to_date(v, 'FXMM/DD/YYYY');
    return 'OK';
exception
    when others then
        return 'KO';    
end;
```

What it does:

```
with test(col) as (
    select '11/30/2017' from dual union all
    select '11/30//2017' from dual union all
    select '11-30-2017' from dual union all
    select '11/30/17' from dual
)    
select col, checkDate(col)
from test
```

gives:

```
COL         CHECKDATE 
----------- ----------
11/30/2017  OK        
11/30//2017 KO        
11-30-2017  KO        
11/30/17    KO
```